# What are the strange curved lines appearing on fabric in my apparel photos, and how can I remove them?

Tags: post-processing, artifacts, moire, clothing

I ran a clothing photography shoot and encountered an issue in many photos.

If you see this image, there are some curved lines all over the item.

What are they and how could I remove them with Photoshop?

[image]

Comment: "When the moon hits your eye, like a big pizza pie, that's a moiré"

Comment: @lharby - I had a good chuckle at this comment.

Answer (score 2):

> What are they and how could I remove them on Photoshop?

That's called *moiré* -- it's similar to what you see on TV when someone wears a shirt or tie with narrow stripes that seem to vibrate. If you search for something like *remove moire in photoshop* you'll find plenty of articles with advice for removing. [Here's one from photographylife.com.](https://photographylife.com/how-to-remove-moire-in-photoshop). An alternative is to use a photo editing program like Lightroom that has a tool for removing moiré built-in.